# Storing multidimensional data

Tags: mysql

I need to store business hours in db. Is it better to create a new table and add

- BusinessID
- weekDay
- hourOpen
- hourClosed

or add a separate column to an existing business info table, with 15K rows and just implode multidimensional array and add to that table?

Comment: The first rule of fight club: do not put more than one atomic value in a column. So there is no other option: yes, add a table. If it's *that* table depends on your requirements. It currently does not support e.g. closing during midday or, more complicated rules like "closed every other monday" or "open until 10pm on the last saturday of the month". But these are just minor details, as long as you have a seperate table.

Comment: OK, cool. I was leaning this way too, just needed a confirmation from someone with more db experience.